# What is the maximum speed a car can reach in TrackMania Nations Forever?

Tags: trackmania-forever

What is the maximum speed that we can reach in TrackMania? This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9l698ooWJqw) seems to show that it is 1000, but does the car actually goes faster than 1000 (i.e. the "1000" limit is just a display limit, but not an actually one)?

Answer (score 1):

The top speed is 1000 kph, my reasoning is that no where it suggests that the speed goes above that every where you look, you'll see that they say "above 900 kph" or "[about 900kph](http://maniaplanet.wikia.com/wiki/Stadium#Gameplay)". I only found one other reference where they mention going 1000 kph and that is in a [review](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/975990-trackmania-2-canyon/reviews/review-148071)

It is unlikely that the display limit would be set to 1000, because, if it shows 4 digits, in theory it should be able to go to 9999.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks! Is it true for all games of the TrackMania series?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I do not know, but my guess would be that it is the case for most, if not all of the TM games. But I might be wrong.

Comment: @Renier at least for canyon (so also valley and stadium, basicly the TM2 series) and the nations forever it is